# InnoDB deadlocks when using LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I'm aware that InnoDB can detect and resolve deadlocks on row-level, but what happens when you use `LOCK TABLES`?

For some reasons I find it **occasionally** easier to lock an entire table than to figure out the logic of avoiding potential deadlocks.

So, let's assume you do:

```
LOCK TABLES tableA WRITE, tableB WRITE
```

Now, two transactions (`T1` and `T2`) attempt this at the same time. For some reason we assume that `T1` could not acquire a lock on `tableA`, but could get one for `tableB`.
Then `T2` comes along, gets a lock on `tableA` but not on `tableB` (`T1` has that). These two now wait for each other. What happens?

1. Is this how the locks would be granted; regardless of the order specified by `LOCK TABLES`? If not then would it not mean that two identical statements could never deadlock each other?
2. Is there a way to handle this properly? Must it just time out?

According to the manual, it **is** okay to use `LOCK TABLES` within a transaction, as specified here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOCK TABLES` (and you need to say `READ` or `WRITE`, etc) will lock all the tables simultaneously.  There is no chance of two multi-table `LOCK` statements getting into a deadlock.  `UNLOCK TABLES` unlocks them simultaneously.

Comment: Oh yea, forgot the R/W part (in my question only obviously). And great, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rick James excellent answer, +1. But why in the documentation does it say that LOCK TABLES and autocommit = 0; with InnoDB tables can detect deadlocks? thanks in advance

Comment: @Daniel - I don't know.  I simply avoid `LOCK TABLES` when using InnoDB.